# Percentage as user input

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to add percentage as a user input ?
Google didn't help.

[image]

Thax in advance

**Update**

Here is a simple code :-

```
dialy_average = float(input('Average daily increase: '))
print(dialy_average)
```

Here is output :-

```
Average daily increase: 30%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jimsrc\Desktop\repo\New folder\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    dialy_average = float(input('Average daily increase: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30%'
```

Comment: What? What do you mean by user input? Just add the percent symbol....

Comment: Do you mean just have a user enter "30%" from an `input()` prompt? You can just slice off the last character and convert the rest of the string into a number.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I am beginner. can you show me, please ?

Comment: `int(input("Average daily increase: ")[:-1])/100`

Comment: @Guimoute Isn't this hardcoded ? What happens if someone enters 50 % ?

Comment: @Jims-Rc Guimoute's expression is not hardcoded. Notice the `[:-1]`. This means "everything before the last character" - in other words, it omits the last character (`%`) from the string. The remainder of your string (`"50 "`) will still parse as the number `50` if you call `int()` or `float()` on it.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Describe (and give examples of) all permissible user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the user to add characters to the input, you can parse it with regular expression:

```
import re

per_raw = input()
per_str = re.findall("([0-9]+)%", per_raw)[0]
per = float(per_str)
```

This does not check for errors. If you to support decimal dot, you need to choose a different expression.

In other languages there's a function called `scanf` which is a bit more simple, but in python there's no equivalent currently.

Comment: It works, but if OP doesn't know how to `rstrip` or slice a "%" character I doubt they want to use regex.

Comment: @Guimoute I'm having trouble with turtle graphics. Do you know any reference or a place to start learning ?

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you want -

```
daily_average=float(input(‘Daily average increase - ‘).replace(‘%’,’’))/100
```

Comment: This statement does not work